# Put a key in Redis via C#

Tags: c#, redis

I am trying to build custom DLL which puts a particular key to Redis key-value storage. I builds, executes, but doesnt do anything. No key added. This is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using TSLab.Script;
using TSLab.Script.Handlers;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace TSLab.pmus
{
    [HandlerCategory("Redis")]
    [InputsCount(2)]
    public class WriteToRedis : ITwoSourcesHandler, ISecurityInput0, IDoubleInputs, IDoubleReturns, IStreamHandler, IValuesHandlerWithNumber, IContextUses
    {
        private ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
        public IContext Context { set; private get; }
        [HandlerParameter(Name = "table", NotOptimized = true)]
        public int table { get; set; }
        [HandlerParameter(Name = "key", Default = "mykey", NotOptimized = true)]
        public string key { get; set; }

        public IList<double> Execute(ISecurity sec, params IList<double>[] dataArr)
        {
            return new double[0];
        }

        public double Execute(ISecurity sec, ConnectionMultiplexer redis, params double[] dataArr)
        {
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase(table);
            db.StringSet("testKey", "Test string");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us how are you configuring it in startup?

Comment: @user3401335 This code is designed to be a plugin for software called TSLab. I link some dependencies for DLL's that use TSLab.Script and TSLab.Script.Handlers, like it said in its documentation. It builds correctly, just does not work as intended.

Comment: If you debug it: which if the two Execute APIs gets executed? If it is the first one, then: you're not doing anything.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yep. You are absolutely right!

Answer (score 1):

As @MarcGravell said, the problem was in two 'Execute' methods.
I changed code to:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using TSLab.Script;
using TSLab.Script.Handlers;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace TSLab.pmus
{
 
    [HandlerCategory("Redis")]
    [InputsCount(2)]
    public class WriteToRedis : ITwoSourcesHandler, ISecurityInput0, IDoubleInputs, IDoubleReturns, IStreamHandler, IValuesHandlerWithNumber, IContextUses
    {
        private ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
        public IContext Context { set; private get; }
        [HandlerParameter(Name = "table", NotOptimized = true)]
        public int table { get; set; }
        [HandlerParameter(Name = "key", Default = "mykey", NotOptimized = true)]
        public string key { get; set; }

        public IList<double> Execute(ISecurity sec, params IList<double>[] dataArr)
        { 
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase(table);
            db.StringSet("testKey", "Test string");
            return new double[0];
        }
    }
}
```

And now it works fine.